# Spring Boot graphQl autoconfiguration fails to instantiate graphQlSource at app startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot app that uses spring-webflux and spring-graphql. At startup, the auto-configuration mechanism cannot instantiate the graphQlSource bean because it fails to run a factory method in its underlying dependencies:

```
Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'annotatedControllerConfigurerDataFetcherExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'annotatedControllerConfigurerDataFetcherExceptionResolver' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'annotatedControllerConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'cursorStrategy' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration$GraphQlDataAutoConfiguration.class]: **Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.data.pagination.EncodingCursorStrategy]: Factory method 'cursorStrategy' threw exception with message: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo$Value","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext"}**
```

I've stared at the Maven dependency tree, and I can't find what lib incompatibility is creating this issue.
Here are the versions I'm using:
Spring Boot 3.1.7
Spring WebFlux 6.0.15
Spring GraphQl 1.2.4 (through spring-boot-starter-graphql 3.1.7)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: one the types in my schema had a field called "value", which the schema parser did not like.